# Text and input box align in form

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to align text to the left side and the input box to the right side.

This is how my site looks like and this is how it should be: [PICTURE REMOVED]

However, I did what I wanted by using div tag inside a div tag, so, if I give background colour to it, this is how it looks like:

The problem is, after green (on the grey side) I would like to echo errors. But because of the div width of the green area, I cannot do that. Error goes under input box. So, I wonder how can I be able to show form like I did in pictures but at the same time able to show errors on the right side, as well.

So, the script calls javascript plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org). And this plugin add error right after input box, when it sees a problem. That's why I am not able to put the errors in another div tag.

error will appear in this class: "label.error". If there is way to make this class "don't care fixed width" in css. That would work.

Comment: Create a container DIV and put 2 DIVs next to eachother inside it. Use CSS to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly what you want to do is create a container `<div />` element and put 2 `<div />` elements inside it. Since you didn't give any code, I can only give you an example:

```css
#container {
    width: 512px;
    height: 506px;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    display: block;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        Form here
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        Errors here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to tell something. I validate inputs with a jQuery plugin and it outputs the error automatically right after input box. So, either I have to modify validator or find another way. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: @cyonder And that's exactly why you should post your code. No one can give you an answer that'll work for you if we have no idea what you need for your specific situation.

Comment: I guess, I should put the text in a div on the left side, and the input boxes in div on the right side. Similar to you idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is a UI/UX issue and surprisingly I'm shocked no one mentioned using a table with div's.

Because your picture was removed I can't really compare the UI, but to make this a simple answer for Text to the left and Textbox to the right see below.
(JS is just to show how it does work)

```js
function updateText(){
var txtStrng=document.getElementById("txtTextbox1").value;
document.getElementById("lblText").innerHTML=txtStrng;

}
```

```html
<form action="" >
<table width="100%" height="71" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="45%"><div align="left"><label id="lblText">Test</label></div></td>
    <td width="55%"><div align="right">
      <input type="text" name="txtTextbox1" id="txtTextbox1" value="Test" onkeyup="updateText();" />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```